# Javascript trigger touchEvent

Tags: javascript, dom, touch-event

How can I trigger a touchEvent(start/motion/end) from a javascript function for a DOM element with specified id?
Sample html page follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Example</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p id="info"></p>      
  <div id="data"></div>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
```

Suppose here touchEvent is needed for 'data' div element.

I'm very new to javascript, so any kind of sources are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery with the syxtax

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('#data').click() // or whatever you want here
})
```

you can reference to http://jquery.com to get the function to do with your div tag

Comment: I would rather need a touch(as from touch-screen devices) than just a click event.

Comment: as from touch-screen devices ? you mean mouse on ? so you can use .hover() function with jquery

Comment: not sure; you see, there are examples on the net like obj.addEventListener('touchmove', function(event) {...}); where obj is a canvas and the function draws on canvas when a touch event occured. Now, what I need is exactly the opposite: suppose I have a canvas which is being drawn and I want to trigger touchEvent in the function that draws on canvas.